Why does node --version show it its present, but npm --version throws and error?
node -- version
23.0.0
npm --version

throw error:
Error: cannot find module 'semver'

It then gives me a long list of require stack
then
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
followed by requireStack: [the path]
I have already added both to my path

This issue can occur if the npm installation is incomplete or has corrupt dependencies.
try,
Reinstall npm
First, try reinstalling npm to restore any missing dependencies.
npm install -g npm

Clear npm Cache
Clearing the npm cache can help if there are any corrupt cache files.
npm cache clean --force

Manually Install semver
Try manually installing semver
npm install -g semver

If the issue still isn't resolved, a full reinstall of Node.js may fix it.

No matter what I do, it continues to throw the same error, I have uninstalled node several times already.  Even when I ran the command in the command prompt as administrator
